# Scolling issue on iphone table view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Scrolling on my table view is very slow despite of the fact that I am using cell identifiers and de-queuing the cells. Scrolling looks a little shaky. What could be the reason?

Comment: How are you doing it? Can you produce relevant code from the cell init.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be an unholy amount of subviews on each cell. You need to explain your cell composition to get a more helpful answer. See [UIImage in uitableViewcell slowdowns scrolling table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841791/uiimage-in-uitableviewcell-slowdowns-scrolling-table/5842159#5842159).